# GemfireXD - PreparedStatement setArray for String(VARCHAR) array not working

Tags: java, jdbc, gemfire

I have some `JDBC` code as follows where I am using gemfireXD as `DB`.

I am trying to parallelize the execution of a procedure on a list of inputs. The size of the list I am passing as the parameter to the procedure is not fixed and it is determined after the execution of the query in the code below. This list can be too big in size.

**Code:**

```
 private static void executeProc (Connection cxn) throws SQLException {

          Statement stmt = null;
          try {
                 stmt = cxn.createStatement();

                 stmt.execute("select distinct field1 from Table1");
                 ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                 List<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<String> ();
                 while (rs.next()) {
                       fieldList.add(rs.getString("field1"));
                 }
                 Array fieldArray = cxn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", fieldList.toArray(new String[fieldList.size()]));
                 CallableStatement callableStmt = cxn.prepareCall("{CALL procedure1() ON TABLE Table1 WHERE field1 IN (?)}");
                 callableStmt.setArray(1, fieldArray);
                 callableStmt.execute();
          } catch (SQLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
   }
```

**Error:**
while executing the code it is giving below runtime error.

*Feature not Implemented : createArrayOf(String, Object[])*

**Question:**

The gemfireXD documentation says Data Aware procedure can be executed passing a list using setArray method. But when I am working on actual API, the setAaary() method is expecting an Array Object instead of a List.

GemfireXD document gives an example of such procedure call in its documentation (1.4.0) which supports setArray() method. The direct example from the documentation is as follows: -

// GemFire XD data-aware procedure invocation.

*CallableStatement callableStmt = connection.prepareCall("{CALL order_credit_check() ON TABLE Orders WHERE customerID IN (?)}"); 
callableStmt.setArray(1, <-list of customer IDs->);*

How do I call preparedStatement.setArray to set the parameter in the query?

Could any one please suggest any other implementation approch to achieve the desired result?

Comment: In a lot of database, you can't use an (SQL) ARRAY for an `IN` condition even if the database itself supports arrays, but given the error you get it is entirely possible that gemfire doesn't support arrays. So check if gemfire supports `ARRAY` at all, and if it does, if it support `createArrayOf`, and if it supports `ARRAY` in `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

GemFire XD does not support Array data type so createArrayOf method will not work.

For the kind of query in you question where you want to use in-list in the where clause, you may have to set each individual value as a parameter

```
CallableStatement callableStmt = cxn.prepareCall("{CALL procedure1() ON TABLE Table1 WHERE field1 IN (?, ?, ?)}");
callableStmt.setInt(1, 1);
callableStmt.setInt(2, 2);
callableStmt.setInt(3, 3);
....
```

Comment: Thanks Sirish for the answer! But the problem is, the size of the list of inputs is not fixed and will be decided from the query getting executed before invoking the procedure call.

Comment: GemfireXD document gives an example of call in its documentation (1.4.0) which supports setArray() method. The direct example from the documentation is as follows: - 

// GemFire XD data-aware procedure invocation */
CallableStatement callableStmt = connection.prepareCall("{CALL order_credit_check() ON TABLE Orders WHERE customerID IN (?)}");
callableStmt.setArray(1, <list of customer IDs>);

Comment: But when I am working on actual API, the setAaary() method is expecting an Array Object instead of a List.

Comment: setArray will not work since Array data type is not supported. The doc needs a correction to remove reference to setArray.

Comment: Thanks Shirish for the clarification! In that case what should be the approch to parallelize the procedure call that gemfireXD supports? if not procedure call, Is there any other approch to achive the desired result?

Comment: One way could be construct your query string dynamically, for example in your case you may keep on adding the in-list markers in where clause to the query

Comment: @ Shirish! How should I retrive the parameter inside the procedure? Should I have to use "ProcedureExecutionContext" - .getFilter() method?

Comment: My full requirement is expalianed in a separate question in following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901922/gemfirexd-how-to-parallelize-data-processing-for-bigger-data-size/30950678#comment49974111_30950678