# GemfireXD - How to parallelize data processing for bigger data size

Tags: java, gemfire

I am using JDBC to process some data where I am using gemfireXD as DB which is an InMemory data grid and a NewSQL solution.

Step1 - I am getting all distinct keys(field1) from a table (Table1)

```
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             stmt.execute("select distinct field1 from Table1");
             ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
             List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String> ();
             while (rs.next()) {
                   keyList.add(rs.getString("field1"));
             }
```

Step2 - I am querying the same table for each key from the above list. This should return me 2 records for each key.

I need to process these 2 records for each key and create one final processed record out of these 2 rows for the key, which finally need to be stored in a separate table (table2).

```
    for (int i = 0; i< fieldList.size(); i++) {
        stmt.execute("select * from Table1 where field1=" + keyList.get(i));
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

        // the resultset should contain 2(or more) rows for the key which need to be processed based on some logic.
        // Finally need to create 1 processed record for the given key.
        // Insert the processed record to Table2
    }
```

Since I have millions of records in Table1, The above way of processing data is time consuming.

I need to parallelize the processing in gemfireXD.

I can do this same processing in PIG or SPARK within few hours using their parallel processing features(creating Tuples/bags of records and using MR programming).

I am hoping gemfireXD must have some facilities to do parallel processing of data, though I have tried DATAAWARE procedure in gemfireXD and used it to parallelize the procedure call, but it did not work for me.

I am hoping gemfire XD must have some other approach for this purpose

Could any one please suggest any implementation approach in gemfireXD to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

**I missed that you're using a NoSQL database. Still, my answer may apply.**

> I need to parallelize the processing in gemfireXD.

You (most probably) don't. You surely need to access the DB efficiently:

- use prepared statements(*)
- use some SQL power

---

For example, use the statement

```
select * from Table1 order by field1
```

read two rows (or, more generally, read until `field1` changes) and process them. Save yourself millions of queries!

---

While `ORDER BY` may be inefficient for a NoSQL database, you can surely do better than millions of queries as they mean millions of round trips with waiting and waiting. For example, you could issue 1000 range queries loading 1000 rows into memory each.

---

(*) IMHO all performance-related questions using something like `where field1=" + keyList.get(i)` should be closed immediately. Concatenated SQL is plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks maaartinus for the answer! The approch you mentioned may save some time but it will not solve my problem. I am using gemfireXD which is a inMemory data grid and a NewSQL solution.

Comment: I can do this same processing in PIG or SPARK within few hours using their parallel processing features(creating Tuples/bags of data and using MR programming). I am hoping gemfireXD must have some facilities to do paralle processing of data, though I have tried DATAAWARE procedure and using it to parallelize the procedure call, but it did not work for me. I am hoping gemfire XD must have some other approch for this purpose.

Comment: @RajibPanda I know nothing about gemfireXD, but it surely allows to restrict the result set somehow. So you can start `threadA` processing only records with `field1 LIKE 'A%'`, `threadB` processing records with `field2 LIKE 'B%'`, and so on. Anyway, using parallel processing, you may *in theory* get a factor close to the number of cores, but using millions of queries you lose more. A few hours for million rows looks slow to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you may be looking into ways to process only keys that may be local to that node so you can distributed the processing as you have said, using DAP (Data Aware Procedures) in a partitioned table.

Partitioning will take care of sharding your data, then you can process it using a DAP querying local data (local to that particular node) and insert it back into your table2. The other consideration here is colocation, since you may actually need some colocation in order to make both tables somehow to be collocated according to some business logic.

Please take a look at the DAP merge sort example.

If you are still having problems with DAP's please share the details or exceptions you may be getting.

Hope that helps.

References:

- http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfirexd/developers_guide/topics/server-side/dap-impl-processor-mergesort-procedure.html
- http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfirexd/getting_started/topics/data_aware_procedures.html
- http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfirexd/developers_guide/topics/create-partition-tables/PartitioningTablesExplained.html
- http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfirexd/data_management/partitioning-colocating.html

Comment: ! Yes you got my issue correctly. Let me give you the exact issue i am getting. I have created a DAP and calling the DAP as metioned in the 2nd link you have provided. But I am getting exception. The details of the issue is explained in following link in a separate question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800266/gemfirexd-preparedstatement-setarray-for-stringvarchar-array-not-working

Comment: The exact issue is in setting the VARCHAR array argument getting passed to the DAP as explained in the question in the other link I provided here.

Comment: Well, indeed you can't use setArray so just iterate over that data and set using IN as suggested by Shirish.

You can iterate over the params of a prepared statement through pstm.getParameterMetaData() for example.

In other words, DAP + local query + Partitioned table -  Solve your problem of distributed processing.  You now just need to understand how to set your Array for the statement using a list and passing using IN clause.

Comment: ! How should I retrive the parameter inside the procedure? Should I have to use "ProcedureExecutionContext" - .getFilter() method?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use join instead of process them one by one?

GemfireXD can use joins when 2 tables are colocated.

I recommend you create another table to store your first query and partition it using the same partition key with your table and then join them to get your result. Let's make call your original table as table1 and the temporary table as tmp. You can get your result using the following query. It should be much faster than your iterative method

```
select s.* from table1 s join tmp t on s.field1=t.field1
```